# Can i check if a session is active throught the code instead at page load?

Tags: php, session

I remember that a question related to the session requiere a code placed above the page, before any kind of html result.
Assuming that session_start() is correctly placed above, can i call the "is_Logged" function throught the body of the page?

In other word i've an admin panel with some option accessible without change the page. The risk is that the user could click on the options box while his session is expired, so for every "click" i've to check if it's still active..
Can i use the is_Logged function, or it's necessary to do an AJAX call?

UPDATE:
What i mean is something like this

```
//some html code

    $('#impostazioniAccount').click(function(e){ 
       parent.location.hash = "sezioneImpostazioniAccount";

       <?php if(!isLogged())
       {
         header("location:../main/");
         exit;  
       }

    function isLogged()
    {return $_SESSION['user'];}

 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, check your **[`session_id()`](https://www.php.net/session-id)**. If it returns an empty string, session is not set. If you want to be able to tell from the client-side, you'll need to use AJAX.

Comment: can i check this throught any point of the page?
I've updated the question

Comment: @AnnaLica: You can check from PHP's point of view. Like I said, if you want to know from the JavaScript side, you'll need AJAX.